# Is there any rule against finding out the gender of a fetus?

Tags: halacha, medicine, pregnancy-birth

From my unscientific survey of what I've seen, it seems like most Orthodox Jews avoid finding out the gender of their child while it is still in utero (even if they otherwise take ultrasounds, blood tests, etc.). Do any sources mention this phenomena and discuss whether there is any legitimate Halachic basis for this practice?

Comment: My guess is that since one can only find out once it's too late to change, people are afraid hearing the gender might lead to tefilos shav if they want the other gender. Of course there are other tefilos shav listed in the gemara, but this one is common.

Comment: @user6591 it's a tefilas shav regardless after 40 days...

Comment: @robev that was my point.